# UserIdentity and session issue

Tags: yii

I have the following class. But when I try to access the `Yii::app()->user->realName;` it generates an error.

I can't understand it all. please help!

Following code is the code of my `UserIdentity` class.

```
<?php

/**
 * UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
 * It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
 * data can identity the user.
 */
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

    public $id, $dmail, $real_name;

    /**
     * Authenticates a user.
     * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
     * are both 'demo'.
     * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
     * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
     * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
     */
    public function authenticate() {
        $theUser = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                    'email' => $this->username,
                   // 'password' => $this->password
                ));
        if ($theUser == null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->id = $theUser->id;
            $this->setState('uid', $this->id);
         //   echo $users->name; exit;
          //  $this->setState('userName', $theUser->name);
            $this->setState("realName",$theUser->fname .' '. $theUser->lname);
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return!$this->errorCode;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend the CWebUser class to achieve the results you want.

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser{
    protected $_realName = 'wu_default';

    public function getRealName(){
        $realName = Yii::app()->user->getState('realName');
        return (null!==$realName)?$realName:$this->_realName;
    }

    public function setRealName($value){
        Yii::app()->user->setState('realName', $value);
    }
}
```

You can then assign and recall the `realName` attribute by using `Yii::app()->user->realName`.

The `protected $_realName` is optional, but allows you to define a default value. If you choose not to use it, change the return line of the `getRealName` method to `return $realName`.

Place the above class in `components/WebUser.php`, or anywhere that it will be loaded or autoloaded.

Change your config file to use your new WebUser class and you should be all set.

```
'components'=>
    'user'=>array(
        'class'=>'WebUser',
    ),
...
),
```